# Magento 2 display a category's product listing with its layered navigation on home page?

Tags: php, layout, home-page, magento2.2.2

I am using **Magento 2.2.2**

I want to display a particular category products on homepage along with its respective *layered navigation*.

What I have already tried:

**1)** Changed home page layout to "2 columns with left bar"

**2)** Added a widget in home page content from admin for category id 1. Enabled pagination.

But I am not getting the default listing header for changing the product listing and neither it is displaying the layered navigation for this category on home page.

Check this image :
[image]

Is there any issue with this approach

Can you tell me if my approach is right or I am missing something to achieve my task.

Or is there a way that I could display a category page as my home page and the URL still remains the websites URL only i.e. nothing more than *www.website.com*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to achieve this:

Added a new category in admin and added all the products that I needed on home page with '**include in menu**' set to '**no**'.

Now in *admin > store > configuration > general > web > default pages*

Added category id as '*catalog/category/view/id/your_cat_id*' in field '**Default Web URL**'

By following above steps you can have any category on home page.